# clarification over Hyperledger-indy and soverin foundation project?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

**Problem:**

> I am studying Hyperledger indy, self-sovereign-identity these days.
>   But I have been very confused on some aspects. Because some article
>   says sovereign is publicly available blockchain. If so I would like to
>   know how we can do development like Ethereum?.

I need clarification sovereign codebase is the Hyperledger-indy project so Hyperledger indy also a publicly available blockchain or we are able to set up locally Hyperledger-indy like what we do in Hyperledger fabric?

And I would like to know in Self sovereign identity issuer create an identity and give it to the owner. In the blockchain, it adds the transaction data and also the hash of the Verify claim. `So I want to know what is the owner shows to the bank or whatever the party to verify their identity and how the verification handle.`

> If someone gives me a brief understanding of these concepts it would
>   be a great help to me. I search about these a lot on the internet but
>   I was unable to find a good and easy understanding of these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because some article says sovereign is publicly available blockchain.

Sovrin is a governed copy of Hyperledger Indy. You can install a copy of Indy yourself, and keep a list of distributed identities on a public ledger, just like they did. Indy and Sovrin are both used to keep a list of distributed identifiers.

In the world of Self-Sovereign Identity, you create your own identity using your agent, which is the program on your machine that manages your identity for you. A wallet is a type of agent, and that's actually where most of the magic happens.

Hyperledger Aries provides a near complete identity solution. The wallet created by Aries can create a SSI which gives you the almost unlimited ability to use that identity in a private context.

When you communicate with anything in Aries/Indy, you create a pairwise pseudonym which is only used for the individual you are communicating with. The pseudonyms are created locally, by Aries.

Indy comes in when your specific use case requires trust roots, you wish to facilitate key echange, or if you need a certificate authority (trust nexus) to distribute sybil free tokens.

In SSI
A certificating authority, like Faber College can give Alice a set of credentials that allows Alice to prove she has a Masters Degree. Alice can present the state proof to a potential employer, and the employer can be certain that Faber College did give Alice a Masters, and that can even be done without any communication taking place. State proofs. Zero Knowledge Proofs. All done swimmingly without the use of Indy.

Indy helps people check that the DiD that says "Faber College" is THE Faber College by introducing a trusted third party, and it also makes revoking credentials easier.

All this is done according to recent W3C standards on DiDs. The identities created by Sovrin/Indy/Aries are completely compatible with the next generation of service providers. The root identity that you create tomorrow could be with you for the rest of your life, in a way.